# Permutation of a list where numbers must change its position in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to solve this question for my assignment.

The predicate acceptable_permutation(L,R) should succeed only if R represents an acceptable permutation of the list L.
For example: [2,1,3] is not an acceptable permutation of the list [1,2,3] because 3 did not change its position.

The outputs are ***supposed*** to be like this:

```
?- acceptable_permutation([1,2,3],R).
R = [2,3,1] ;
R = [3,1,2] ;
false

?- acceptable_permutation([1,2,3,4],R).
R = [2,1,4,3] ;
R = [2,3,4,1] ;
R = [2,4,1,3] ;
R = [3,1,4,2] ;
R = [3,4,1,2] ;
R = [3,4,2,1] ;
R = [4,1,2,3] ;
R = [4,3,1,2] ;
R = [4,3,2,1] ;
false.
```

My outputs of my code however gives:

```
?- acceptable_permutation([1,2,3],R).
R = [1,2,3] ;
R = [1,3,2] ;
R = [2,1,3] ;
R = [2,3,1] ;
R = [3,1,2] ;
R = [3,2,1] ;

?- acceptable_permutation([1,2,3,4],R).
R = [1,2,3,4] ;
R = [1,2,4,3] ;
R = [1,3,2,4] ;
R = [1,3,4,2] ;
R = [1,4,2,3] ;
R = [1,4,3,2] ;
R = [2,1,3,4] ;
R = [2,1,4,3] ;
R = [2,3,1,4] ;
R = [2,3,4,1] ;
R = [2,4,1,3] ;
R = [2,4,3,1] ;
R = [3,1,2,4] ;
R = [3,1,4,2] ;
R = [3,2,1,4] ;
R = [3,2,4,1] ;
R = [3,4,1,2] ;
R = [3,4,2,1] ;
R = [4,1,2,3] ;
R = [4,1,3,2] ;
R = [4,2,1,3] ;
R = [4,2,3,1] ;
R = [4,3,1,2] ;
R = [4,3,2,1] ;
false.
```

My code is the following:

```
acceptable_permutation(list,list).

del(symbol,list,list).

del(X,[X|L1], L1).

del(X,[Y|L1], [Y|L2]):-
    del(X,L1, L2).
    acceptable_permutation([] , []).

acceptable_permutation(L, [X|P]):-
    del(X, L, L1),
    acceptable_permutation(L1, P).
```

Please tell me where exactly the problem is, so that my outputs should match the correct outputs. I would appreciate a lot if you show me how exactly it is done.

Comment: What do you expect for `acceptable_permutation([1,2,2],L)`?

Comment: @false Well there shouldn't be repeated numbers in a list according to the assignment. Anyway someone have already answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't check that all the elements of the output list are in a different position than the input list. You should add a predicate to check this, like that:

```
perm(L,LO):-
    acceptable_permutation(L,LO),
    different_place(L,LO).

different_place([A|T0],[B|T1]):-
    A \= B,
    different_place(T0,T1).
different_place([],[]).

?- perm([1,2,3],R).
R = [2, 3, 1]
R = [3, 1, 2]
false
```

Improvement 1: instead of creating your own predicate (in this case, `different_place/2`), you can use `maplist/3` with `\=/2` in this way:

```
perm(L,LO):-
    acceptable_permutation(L,LO),
    maplist(\=,L,LO).
```

Improvement 2: swi prolog offers the predicate `permutation/2` that computes the permutations of a list. So you can solve your problem with only three lines:

```
find_perm(L,LO):-
    permutation(L,LO),
    maplist(\=,L,LO).

?- find_perm([1,2,3],L).
L = [2, 3, 1]
L = [3, 1, 2]
false
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your detailed explanation. I also appreciate you showed me improvements for the code. Thank you.

Comment: Consider [tag:prolog-dif]

Comment: While `A = a, find_perm([A,b],[b,A]).` correctly succeeds, its generalization `find_perm([A,b],[b,A]).` fails. This is one of the reasons why `dif/2` is needed. The other is performance.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** A permutation that has no fixed points is called [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). A funny name! TIL that, too.

**2)** Like this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55303792/4609915), we use `maplist/3` and `permutation/2`.

**3)** Unlike this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55303792/4609915), we use [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif) instead of `(\=)/2` **to preserve logical purity**.

[logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) helps keep Prolog programs general, and—in this case—also **increase efficiency**.

Let's define `list_derangement/2` like so:

```
list_derangement(Es, Xs) :-
   maplist(dif, Es, Xs),         % using dif/2
   permutation(Es, Xs).
```

Note that the `maplist/2` goal now precedes the other one!

This can speed up the detection of failing cases, compared to `find_perm/2` from previous answer:

```
?- time(find_perm([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
                  [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_, _,11])).
% 303,403,801 inferences, 37.018 CPU in 37.364 seconds (99% CPU, 8196109 Lips)  
false.

?- time(list_derangement([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 
                         [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_, _,11])).
% 15,398 inferences, 0.009 CPU in 0.013 seconds (67% CPU, 1720831 Lips)         
false.
```

For corresponding ground terms above implementations are of comparable speed:

```
?- time((find_perm([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],_),false)).
% 931,088,992 inferences, 107.320 CPU in 107.816 seconds (100% CPU, 8675793 Lips)
false.

?- time((list_derangement([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],_),false)).
% 1,368,212,629 inferences, 97.890 CPU in 98.019 seconds (100% CPU, 13976991 Lips)
false.
```

Comment: Very deranging this derangement. TIL: in Spanish, it's [subfactorial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subfactorial) and in Italian [dismutatione](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dismutazione_(matematica)). Clearly Italian wins. It's a dis- not a per-mutation!

Comment: @false. Many comparisons would be worthwhile in this example, I guess. My favorite one would be `maplist(dif,...), permutation(...)` vs `permutation(...), maplist(dif,...)` (not `permutation(...), maplist((\=),...)`...